# Reducing number of limit statements

Tags: calculus, limits

I am terrified of making a mistake of forgetting to write lim on every side of a limit expression chain. I always end up forgetting one, and mess up readability of my tests by arrows and statements on top of page.

Is there a way to not write lim all over the page, or write it less often?

for example

$$\begin{align*}\lim _{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}h &= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x^2+2xh+h^2)-x^2}h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{2xh+h^2}h \\&= \lim_ {h\to0}\frac{h(2x+h)}h = \lim_{ h\to0}2x+h = 2x\end{align*}$$

the above had so many $\lim$s... it's aggrevating...

Is there a way to make it obvious that this block's h is a limit, some sort of distributive limit that applies to each individual part of the equality chain?

Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is "No". The longer answer is "No!". It doesn't take that long to write three letters and three symbols underneath. And please note how exploringnet and Raskolnikov typeset your post to make the math symbols appear properly. You might want to have a look at how it was done so you can typeset your own questions properly.

Comment: I understand that it isn't difficult to write, it is just way too easy to forget the lim and invalidate the expression chain. Whereas h in the context appears to be "obviously defined as lim h->0" in this particular block. I believe I read somewhere that I can write the limit normally, and say "as h->0" at the end of the chain, but I am not sure if this is formally valid. Thanks for your response though. PS: Thanks for the edit to my post format :)

Comment: Actually all of the algebra can be done without the limits appended to it (with the supposition that $h \ne 0$ at the penultimate step). E.g. you could write "For all $h \ne 0$, $\dfrac{(x+h)^2-x^2}h = \cdots = 2x+h$. Therefore, $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{(x+h)^2-x^2}h = \lim\limits_{h\to0} 2x+h = 2x$." and that would be a perfectly valid proof avoiding most of the $\lim$s.

Comment: please note that the answer to your question: "Is there a way to make it obvious that this block's h is a limit, some sort of distributive limit that applies to each individual part of the equality chain?" is still 'no'. The answer provided below shows that you can do the algebra first and take limits later, thus avoiding writing lim so much, but these is still no convention for 'making it obvious lims are taken over a block of stuff'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the most complicate part in the proof is writing the lim you are a blessed person. 
I wouldn't recommend it but you can write all steps where you don't take a limit.

That would be like, for $h\neq 0$ we have:
$$\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} = \frac{x^2 +2hx+h^2 -x^2}{h^2}= \frac{2hx+h^2}{h}=\frac{h}{h} \cdot (2x+h)=2x+h$$ 
Hence 
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} 2x+h = 2x $$

You should always think about what is more legible and what makes more sense in the proof.

Comment: @Dmitry when you are going to write really complicated proofs, you think such a lot time at every single step how to write down that you surely won't forget the limit anyway ;)

Comment: Yeah, but in a context of say, taking Calculus 1 where the question only focuses on calculating the limit, especially with more than 4 limits in it, it's almost like playing minesweeper. same as i'd prefer writing 10*x rather than x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x... I lost track of xs.

Comment: @Dmitry nope in minesweeper you can win ;)